# Nice geospatial plot in python

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, geoplot

Would anyone know how the following plot was generated, and if there's any way to do it in python? I couldn't find anything like this in geoplot or geopandas. [local US pop density as peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kdQa.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this plot is produced using several steps in various software. I produced something close to this one myself.

My method was this:

1. generate heatmap raster from data using suitable kernel method.
2. by Using ArcScene (ArcGIS Pro 3D view) I created the 3D visualization mesh.
3. Exporting the 3D view.

From this point you can either do some post processing in Photoshop, or you can export the mesh with texture as a 3D model and use 3D modelling and rendering sofware such as Blender or Rhino.

**Alternative 1:**

Alternatively you can use https://kepler.gl/ to load your data and visualize it. I am not sure that you can get the exact same results, but it should be good enough.

**Alternative 2:**

you can use QGIS and the tutorial [here](https://www.giscourse.com/easy-way-to-export-and-print-3d-dems/) to generate an .STL file to visualize in 3D modelling software and render. However, printing borders and adding text might be a bit challenging.

Comment: Though Rhino3D offers simple rendering, I guess the Flamingo render engine (extension to Rhino3d) would achieve better results in rendering.. ;)

Comment: Rhino and Blender were examples :D. you can use whatever that is available to you ;).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the answer! But there's no comparable packages which can achieve this in open-source R or python? You'd need a licensed version of ArcGis?

Comment: What I can think of (not knowing exactly how) is to convert the heatmap raster to points and use it as a point cloud to load in 3D objects.
You can also use a 3D plot, but won't give you your desired results.
Also, you can check out KeplerGL library. That one is too useful in 3D visualization

Comment: kepler can also be used in python. Jupyter enviroment is advised. https://docs.kepler.gl/docs/keplergl-jupyter

Comment: Ok, all seems a bit too much to invest into for academia :D Thanks for your answer. Can't upvote you because I need 15 reputation unfortunately :<

Comment: @tarquaeron It might be useful for conferences, lectures, and business :D. But try to keep your visualizations readable in 2D format for publishing papers and academia. Do not worry about the upvote. I am happy to help. Up votes and points are just side benefits ;)